# Why isn't loop decrementing cx register?

Tags: assembly, x86, infinite-loop

I'm trying to load sectors from the disk into memory with the following assembly code, but as I figured out with some int 0x10 to the terminal, the reason it's not working is it gets stuck in an infinite loop. I thought loop automatically decremented the cx register for me. Below is the code, with the test show_message left in for you to see how I came to the conclusion that loop is not decrementing cx. What I see is msg_2 "Still in loop" over and over and over again without end.

Another great answer would be why the read never succeeds (why the carry flag is never clear) as I'm very confident the values for the registers are good at the time of the call, but other than those registers' contents not being right, if someone can see something I did wrong in setting up for int 0x13, that would be great too.

One last note: I know about ch being the low eight bits of the cylinder, the two high bits of cl being the two high bits of the cylinder, and the low 6 bits of cl being the sector number. My stuff is at cylinder 0, sector 2, so [CYLNUM] is 0x00 and [SECTNUM] is 0x02.

```
;;;Load Memory;;;

load_mem:

 mov cx, 3        ;Try to read the drive 3 times



read_loop:

  xor ah, ah        ;ah=0, reset drive

  int 0x13            ;Call drive reset



  mov ax, [SYSADDR]

  mov es, ax        ;Destination- es:bx

  mov bx, 0



  mov dl, [DRIVENUM]

  mov dh, [HEADNUM]

  mov al, [NUMKERNELSECTS]

  mov ch, [CYLNUM]

  mov cl, [SECTNUM]

  mov ah, 0x02        ;ah=2, read drive

  int 0x13            ;Call read interrupt

  jnc exit            ;If carry flag is clear, exit
;;test;;
  mov si, msg_2
  call show_message
;;test;;

  loop read_loop

  mov si, read_error    ;Failed 3 times

  call show_message

hang:

  jmp hang            ;hang for now

exit:

  ret
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're modifying CX in your loop:

```
  mov ch, [CYLNUM]

  mov cl, [SECTNUM]
```

CX register consists of CH (Higher byte) and CL (Lower byte).

To avoid that, you could try using PUSH/POP operations on CX (or ECX) before/after the INT invocation (or maybe better at the beginning/end of the loop).

Of course, I may be wrong - I haven't been programming in assembly for 10 years.

Comment: Ah, of course! CX = CHCL, right? I was thinking of them as three different things and forgot that CX is the name for both of them together. So you can't use the loop instruction when you're using CH and/or CL in general, I would presume.

Comment: @Pete see my answer - well, you can use stack (PUSH/POP) to store CX value temporarily.

Comment: Thanks. Now I escape that infinite loop, but the read never succeeds. I guess I need to make 100% sure my drive, head, cylinder, and sector numbers are right because the read never succeeds.

Comment: BEWARE: drive, cylinder and head numbers are zero based, but the first sector is sector 1.

Answer (score 0):

Are "CYLNUM" and the other uppercase symbols actually variables, or are they defined constants (constants are uppercase "by convention" in some languages). If they're variables, your code looks okay. If they're constants, lose the "[]".

(if variables, is ds set correctly?)

Best,
Frank